# Best way to load content with a probability

Tags: php, random, probability

I'm doing some A/B testing on a site of mine, and for various reasons I need a certain piece of content to appear for 1% of the page loads. In other words if the page is loaded 100 times, I would expect my special piece of content to have appeared once.

Using PHP what is the best way to do this?

I could use the rand() function and do something like `if (rand(0,1)>=0.99){//Show content}`

But is there a better or more reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this on a site I developed and it works perfectly.  PHP is server side so its about as reliable as you’re going to get. I would do it this way:

```
<?php if (mt_rand(1, 100) === 100): ?>

// pure html content here

<?php endif ?>
```

EDIT:

The very nature of prabability means that given a large enough sample `mt_rand(1, 100)` will generate the number match you are looking for 1% of the time.  You can do fancy databases or flat files to force the odds, but this is unnecessary as you just need to trust the `mersenne twister` that is does generate your odds correctly.

Comment: `In other words if the page is loaded 100 times, I would expect my special piece of content to have appeared once.` In your case its just random.. It could show the special content multiple times

Comment: So, it must load only a maximum of 1 time in 100 loads?  Is that all loads or loads per IP?

Comment: I don't know, It is not in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not about PHP but more about strategy of doing it.

If you need it to appear exactly for 1% of views, you can use counters with Redis or Memcached or in your database.
- good if your aim is to control exactly number of view.
- NB. if you use Redis or Mamcached, your counters will be reset after server or service restart.

What you proposed with rand() will work the same well but it will be near 1% but not exact 1%. Actually in long run it will move closer to 1%.
- faster as does not require access to redis/memcached/database;
- will appear more randomly, not exactly every 100th view.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go for a rand-solution, given this statement:

> In other words if the page is loaded 100 times, I would expect my special piece of content to have appeared once.

You could potentially never get 99 from rand(0,100).

Create a very simple database table with one column - `counter` - and update it every hit. Include the piece of code every time the counter hits a multiple of 100.